# Reactive Cassandra not storing the message getting from KAFKA

Tags: java, apache-kafka, cassandra

i have been trying to store the message I am getting from different micro-service through Kafka using Reactive cassandra.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this 2 dependency I am using for my serivice.

```
@Autowired
private AuditLogRepository auditLogRepository;


public void saveAuditLog(Flux<AuditLogMessage> auditLogMessageFlux) {

    auditLogMessageFlux.subscribe(auditLogMessage -> {
        AuditLog audit = AuditLog.builder().id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).tenantId(auditLogMessage.getTenantId())
                .logTime(auditLogMessage.getLogTime()).entity(auditLogMessage.getEntity())
                .userId(auditLogMessage.getUserId()).logType(auditLogMessage.getLogType())
                .entityReference(auditLogMessage.getEntityReference()).change(auditLogMessage.getChange()).build();
        auditLogRepository.save(audit);


    }

    );
```

@Repository
public interface AuditLogRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<AuditLog, String> {

}

but if i change my repository from ReactiveCassandra to Cassandra, its working.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what `AuditLogRepository` class looks like, or how your method is actually subscribing to Kafka since you have no KafkaListener annotation, for example, but is there a specific reason not to use Cassandra Kafka Connector?

Comment: @Repository public interface AuditLogRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<AuditLog, String> {
}

Comment: we are having a service to store kafka topic in cassandra

Comment: I can see that. But that technically is also what existing code for Kafka Connect can do. In any case, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that details how your AuditLogMessage model is provided to the method

Answer (score 0):

its resolved. auditLogRepository.save(audit).subscribed();
needed.